# How to read .mp4 file as bytes in c++ and store it in an array

Tags: c++, file, sockets, video, udp

I want to read a .mp4 file as bytes in c++. Finally I need to store to read file as a byte array and send it across a udp socket. This is the code that I have written. The sending code seems fine to me but the file is not getting read properly. Can someone please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "VideoPacket.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class VideoPacket {
public:
    bool flag;
    string filename;
    int packetNum;
    int index;
    char *data;
    time_t timestamp{};

    explicit VideoPacket(bool p_flag, string &p_filename, int p_packetNum, char *p_data, int p_index) {
        flag = p_flag;
        packetNum = p_packetNum;
        index = p_index;
        data = p_data;
        filename = p_filename;
    }
};

vector<VideoPacket> readFile(string &filename) {
    ifstream fin(filename);
    vector<VideoPacket> videoData;
    char buff[4096];

    int counter = 0;
    do {
        fin.read(buff, sizeof(buff));
        cout << buff << endl;
        VideoPacket newPacket(true, filename, -1, buff, counter);
        counter++;
        videoData.push_back(newPacket);
    } while (!fin.eof());
    return videoData;
}

int main() {
    string filename = R"(videoSrc)";
    vector<VideoPacket> videoData = readFile(filename);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue I am facing is that file is not getting read properly. The while loop for reading the file only run once but the file size is 208kb.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `cout << buff << endl;` causes undefined behavior if `buff` doesn't point to a null-terminated string, which it is not if you are just using it as a `read` buffer.

Comment: If your problem is simply with `readFile`, then please remove the rest of the irrelevant code. You should present a [mre]. Remove everything that is not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is not the cause of the problem you are asking about, but storing a `char *` for `data` in the packet is also wrong. You should be storing a `std::string` or similar. Otherwise you are going to just store pointers to the local `buff` array which all become dangling when returning from the function. And that will also require you to pass information about how many bytes should be stored from the `char*` pointer to this `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple logical flaws here.

```
char buff[4096];
```

We begin by declaring this array. So far, so good.

```
        fin.read(buff, sizeof(buff));
```

`read()` reads the next chunk of (hopefully) 4096 bytes. Still doing great.

```
        cout << buff << endl;
```

This is where things go south. This calls an `operator<<` that takes a pointer to a `char` as its parameter. Additionally, this `<<` expects to get a pointer to a C-style string here, with zero or more non-0 bytes, followed by a single 0 byte. That's the string that'll be printed. It is almost a certainty that somewhere in those 4096 bytes, given that this is an MP4 file, there's going to be a whole bunch of 0 bytes there. The first one will do. That's going to be your output, right there. Your output will quickly finish, much sooner than you expected.

And if there just aren't any 0 bytes, in any of those `read()` 4096 bytes, this is going to blow past those 4096 bytes, looking for the trailing 0 byte. You may get all sorts of interesting output, like your vacation pictures, maybe even your Facebook password, etc... It's all going to go to `std::cout`.

```
} while (!fin.eof());
```

And here things can't get any worse than this. `eof()` only returns true ***after*** a read operation fails because the end of file was reached. If you just happen to have read the last 4096 bytes of your MP4 file, `eof()` is still false, so you'll go back to the top, and attempt to read 4096 bytes more. That'll fail. But the shown code is blissfully unaware, it has no idea that this has happened. So, it will attempt to dump the contents of `buf`, which will be exactly the same, and this will dump another random amount of garbage to `std::cout`.

And if the MP4 file's size was not an even multiple of 4096, the last `read()` operation produces partial data, but everything else in the loop still expects that exactly 4096 bytes were read. The overall logic for reading the file is fundamentally flawed.

In conclusion, the following must be fixed:

1. The logic for the output to `std::cout` is flawed, and should be fixed.
2. The logic for reading from the file is flawed, and must be fixed. `gcount()` returns the number of characters that `read()` actually read. The shown code must use that, both for handling the read input, and for end-of-file detection (`gcount()` will return 0).